# How do I use WP_query with multiple post IDs?

Tags: php, wp-query

I want to query multiple posts with an array of IDs (note: I am querying a custom post type).

Here's what I have, which isn't working:

```
$myarray = array(144, 246);

$args = array(
   'post_type' => 'ai1ec_event',
   'p'      => $myarray
);
// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Any tips on how to do this?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Please reference the Codex entry for [post/page parameters for `WP_Query()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters).

The `'p'` parameter takes a single post ID, as an integer.

To pass an *array* of posts, you need to use `'post__in'`:

```
$myarray = array(144, 246);

$args = array(
   'post_type' => 'ai1ec_event',
   'post__in'      => $myarray
);
// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```